# htaccess redirect a page to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

We are trying to redirect a single page from our parent domain to a subdomain:

```
http://foo.com/calendar
http://www.foo.com/calendar
```

redirect to:

```
http://events.foo.com/calendar
```

Using cPanel redirect, it gives us this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.foo\.com$
RewriteRule ^calendar$ "http\:\/\/events\.foo\.com\/calendar\/" [R=301,L]
```

However, the redirect is not working.

RewriteEngine On is included at the start of the htaccess file, as it is a WordPress site.

UPDATE:
Here is the entire htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.foo\.com$
RewriteRule ^calendar$ "http\:\/\/events\.foo\.com\/calendar\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Looking at one of my rules, I don't use quotes, nor escape the characters in the destination URL.  Does `RewriteRule ^calendar$ http://events.foo.com/calendar/ [R=302,L]` work (while you're testing, set the redirect to temporary (302), just in case you mess something up (301s are hard to clear from some browsers))?

Comment: @Hobo Removing the quotes and forward slashes did not help.  Good thought though.

Comment: @anubhava The entire file is now shown above in the UPDATED section

Comment: I tried moving the RewriteRule up into the <IfModule> and that did not work either.

Comment: @anubhava Ok, did that.  Didn't work either.

Comment: I just went ahead and installed a WordPress plugin to take care of it. Issue resolved, although I still can't figure out why htaccess didn't work.